# How do I disable Ping?

Tags: itunes, ping

Although I do like and enjoy using iTunes, I'm not a fan of the new Ping service that Apple has embedded into it.

Is it possible to disable the Ping link under "Store", the Ping sidebar, and the Ping buttons next to each song? If so, how?

Comment: I hate that they give no choices for being anonymous.  Why do I have to use my real full name to sign up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In iTunes 10.1, there’s a setting for that:

[image]

Additionally you can set a parental control that also disables Ping.

Answer (score 7):

You can also restore the old arrow functionality

[image]

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunes show-store-link-arrows 1
```

I also suggest the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunes invertStoreLinks 1
```

> This setting switches the default
>   behaviour of the arrow links. By
>   default (well, by default in iTunes
>   10.0.0 and before) the arrows would send the user to the corresponding
>   page in the iTunes Store, but you
>   could also hold down Opt and click to
>   be redirected to the corresponding
>   list in your own library.
>
> Now, to reset it all to Apple's
>   defaults... you can either do the same
>   lines as above but replacing '1' with
>   '0', or you can delete the settings by
>   changing "write" to "delete" and
>   removing the 1 from the end:

```
defaults delete com.apple.iTunes disablePingSidebar

defaults delete com.apple.iTunes hide-ping-dropdown

defaults delete com.apple.iTunes show-store-link-arrows

defaults delete com.apple.iTunes invertStoreLinks
```

restart when done.

I [blogged](http://livearevolution.com/removing-ping-restoring-arrow-link-itunes-100) about this when I read [Tom Gidden's article](http://gidden.net/tom/2010/09/25/removing-ping-from-itunes-10-0-1/comment-page-2/#comment-34578)

Answer (score 4):

If you dont like playing with the command line, I advise you to install [**Secret**](http://secrets.blacktree.com/).

With this Preferences pane, you'll have access to hidden settings for a lot of applications (from Apple and third parties).

Then, all you have to do is go to the iTunes section and search for "Ping", like so:
[image: preference pane secret]

If you know your way around Terminal.app, here are the commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunes hide-ping-dropdown -bool TRUE
```

and

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunes disablePingSidebar 1
```

Switch to `-bool FALSE` and `disablePingSidebar 0` to if you want the default value again.